# Moving institutions, gap employment, and R21 funding

Tags: funding, professorship

I am currently a research scientist with an R21. I was offered an assistant professor position, but the starting date is after my current appointment ends. What would happen to my funding if I have a gap of employment of a few months? Would I lose my funding?

Comment: Please be so kind to explain acronyms and give your location, as these highly influence the situation.

Comment: This is well beyond an "let's ask random people on the internet" type question. You need to contact your funding body and the financial coordinator of your current (and possible future) university to get an *official* answer that you can rely on and make appropriate plans.